# Check the grammar for "returned back"

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

Is there an error in this sentence?

> When Darun heard the news that his father had been hospitalised he cancelled his trip and returned back to his village.

I think the error is 'back' but I need your confirmation.

Comment: Please note the corrected spelling of _grammar_ (not _grammer_) in the question title.

Comment: Might be a regionalism. Round these parts we don't find things we've lost, we "find them back" e.g. "*I found back my keys. They were in the refrigerator.*"

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - I can't recall ever hearing "I found back my ...".

Comment: returned to his village once again, sounds better.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing ungrammatical about "returned back to his village" even though "back" is slightly redundant. You could say:

> When Darun heard the news that his father had been hospitalised he cancelled his trip and returned to his village.

Comment: However there is a comma missing after the leading dependent clause, "When Darun heard...".

Comment: @hardmath: Very true. I focused on the question asked but you are right that the sentence has other problems.

Comment: Right, although "grammar" only appears in the title.  Body of Question asks, "Is there an error in this sentence?" So if this was a test problem, possibly the OP jumped to an incorrect guess about the nature of any "error".

Comment: But the body question was about any error, and idiomaticity is as important as grammaticality.

Answer (score 1):

The word *back* is implied by the word *return*, so basically it is not necessary to use *back*. Just *return* is enough.

Comment: That is not a grammatical error, though.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is the redundency of using 'returned back'. It is not acceptable, unless a character speaks like that (dialogue, or 1st person narrative). Also, there is a comma missing that indicates time.

> When Darun heard the news that his father had been hospitalised, he cancelled his trip and returned to his village.

Answer (score -6):

'Returned' is not a proper word as of the correct English usage, but is a misconception usually considered a word due to to repetition.
As of 2012, the Oxford dictionary considered it as a word, but its usage is still considered wrong in context of the corseated British English.

Comment: With the exception of the dictionary reference (which is a matter of fact), this answer is completely wrong.

Comment: So how come I can't find the definition of "corseated" anywhere?